# Gnuplot bar chart from this CSV input

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I have csv file data.dat for example with these values:

```
#W=1
0;sqlite;11500
1;hsql;14550
2;h2;17550
#W=2
0;sqlite;11000
1;hsql;13800
2;h2;16500
#W=3
0;sqlite;11000
1;hsql;13800
2;h2;16500
#W=4
0;sqlite;11000
1;hsql;13800
2;h2;16500
```

I need to plot bar charts into pdf. each data for each graph starts with title #W1,#W2....

i have tried this script:

```
 cat << __EOF | gnuplot -persist
 set terminal pdf
 set output 'out.pdf'
 set datafile separator ";"
 set boxwidth 0.5
 set style fill solid
 plot "data2.dat" using 1:3:xtic(2) with boxes
__EOF
```

giving this output:
[image]

how can i make more graphs (4 in this example but there could more or less) from one datafile each graph separately under previous one?

**Edit:**
each graph can have different number of bars not only three as in previous example. File data2.dat could also look like this:

```
#W=1
0;sqlite;11500
1;hsql;14550
2;h2;17550
3;derby;8500
4;sqlite;13550
5;h2;19250
#W=2
0;sqlite;11000
1;hsql;13800
```

This script from Miguel answer works fine when there are 3 bars for each graph but i dont know how to change it to plot more or less bars.

```
cat << __EOF | gnuplot -persist
set terminal pdf
set datafile separator ";"
set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid
do for [i=0:3] {
set output 'out'.i.'.pdf'
plot "data2.dat" using 1:3:xtic(2) every ::(i*3)::(i*3+3) with boxes
}
__EOF
```

also if it would be possible i would like to have a graph tittle according to header value of each dataset (W=1, W=2....)

Comment: I think you'd be more likely to get a reply if you try to make the plot, and make a post where you describe why/how you got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `multiplot` and an outer loop of your `plot` command, or you can iterate within you `plot` command, depending on what you want to achieve. The `every` option allows you to select what to plot from your file.

With `multiplot`:

```
set multiplot layout 2,2
set datafile separator ";"
set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid
do for [i=0:3] {
plot "data2.dat" using 1:3:xtic(2) every ::(i*3)::(i*3+3) with boxes
}
```

[image]

Within a single plot:

```
set datafile separator ";"
set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid
plot for [i=0:3] "data2.dat" using 1:3:xtic(2) every ::(i*3)::(i*3+3) with boxes
```

[image]

In your case, since the last 3 blocks in your file are the same you don't get to visualize above the 2nd and 3rd blocks, which remain hidden under the 4th one.

To have the graphs plotted in independent files again you just need to loop, but now changing the file name for each iteration:

```
set terminal pdf
set datafile separator ";"
set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid
do for [i=0:3] {
set output 'out'.i.'.pdf'
plot "data2.dat" using 1:3:xtic(2) every ::(i*3)::(i*3+3) with boxes
}
```

The code above will generate files `out0.pdf`, `out1.pdf`, etc.

Comment: thanks for reply but i would like to have each graph separately if its possible. in the file data2.dat there could be also more than 4 datasets.

Comment: @user3616643 It was not clear from your question what exactly you wanted to do. I updated the answer, the last part should fix your problem.

Comment: this is almost what i wanted. is there any simple solution to make graphs with different number of bars with this script? i have tried to modify but cant find right solution.

Comment: @user3616643 The easiest way to do that is by formatting your data file so that there is an empty line between data blocks. Then you can select which block you want to plot by changing the `every` part to `every :::i::i`.